# Youtube Get Thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, api, youtube

Trying to do a few things in my new Wordpress Youtube niche theme. I have a tab in my theme for the user to input the Youtube watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx id. When they enter the xxxxxxxxxxx url it outputs the video, showing 16 posts per tab via the 'loop' query.

Working example [here](http://www.elevancement.com/)

I have looked into this Google developer console api thing... and it is complete gibberish to me. I'm using custom post types for the 4 categories youll see on my site. only "Comedy" is populated right now.

NEW EDIT: THIS WORKS. Thank you all who have helped me figure this out!

```
<?php
  $new_query = new WP_Query();
  $new_query->query( array('post_type' => array( 'comedy' ), 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc','showposts' => 16, 'paged'=>$paged ));

  while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

  $url = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'comedy_url', $single = true);

  include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/library/variables.php');

  $code = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $url;
  $json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url='.urlencode($code));
  $video = json_decode($json);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $video->thumbnail_url ?>" />
```

Upon pulling the thumbnail some of you may notice BLACK BORDERS on the top and bottom of your thumbnail. To fix this use the code below:

```
<a href="<? if($code) {?><?php echo $code; ?><? } ?>">
  <div class="yt-thumbnail" style="background:url('<?php echo $video->thumbnail_url ?>') center no-repeat;"></div>
</a>

// in your css file 
.yt-thumbnail{
    height: 164px;
    width: 300px;
    background-size: 300px 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the oEmbed API to get thumbnail, uploader name and title. All you need is to encode the URL of the video, for example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9FOWI6Zftpg
```

This will return a JSON response:

```
{
  "provider_name":"YouTube",
  "version":"1.0",
  "author_url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/NScherzingerVEVO",
  "type":"video",
  "author_name":"NScherzingerVEVO",
  "thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/i1.ytimg.com\/vi\/9FOWI6Zftpg\/hqdefault.jpg",
  "provider_url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
  "title":"Nicole Scherzinger - Your Love",
  "height":270,
  "width":480,
  "thumbnail_height":360,
  "html":"\u003ciframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/9FOWI6Zftpg?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e",
  "thumbnail_width":480
}
```

Getting the view count is a bit more difficult, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331176/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api) for details.

**Edit:**

Here is an example how to get the thumbnail in PHP:

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FOWI6Zftpg';
  $json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url='.urlencode($url));
  $video = json_decode($json);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $video->thumbnail_url ?>" />
```

Comment: This is my misunderstanding... how do I grab the JSON file off ftp? I assume I can do:

    `http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%<? if($url) {?><?php echo $url; ?><? } ?>`

But how would I go about pulling the thumbnail and calling it?

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377244/how-to-correctly-use-oembed-to-pull-thumbs-from-youtube) as well... looking into it.

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Comment: I was able to get this working by changing `$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FOWI6Zftpg';` to `$code = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $url;`, so it still falls in line with my custom fields. Thanks!