# how to get youtube video id from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I am trying to check whether a url is a valid youtube video URL and get the youtube video ID from it, so far I am using a simple javascript split function in order to achieve this, however this has some minor disadvantages as youtube has multiple URL's.

I have been viewing other stackoverflow threads however all of them only support 1 specific URL which is not what I need.

I need something that matches all these URL's:

> http(s)://www.youtu.be/videoID
>
> http(s)://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID

(and optionally any other short URL's which the script automatically detects whether it contains a youtube video)

Any ideas which can be handled by the browser quick/efficient is greatly appreciated!

Comment: edited my question, I also need to check whether or not the URL is a valid youtube video

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript REGEX: How to get youtube video id from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url)

Comment: I use those functions: https://github.com/lingtalfi/video-ids-and-thumbnails/blob/master/function.video.php#L41

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = "...";
var videoid = url.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/);
if(videoid != null) {
   console.log("video id = ",videoid[1]);
} else { 
    console.log("The youtube url is not valid.");
}
```

see regex:

```
/
(?:https?:\/{2})? // Optional protocol, if have, must be http:// or https://
(?:w{3}\.)?      // Optional sub-domain, if have, must be www.
youtu(?:be)?  // The domain. Match 'youtu' and optionally 'be'. 
\.(?:com|be) // the domain-extension must be .com or .be
(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+) //match the value of 'v' parameter in querystring from 'watch' directory OR after root directory, any non-space value.
/
```

Comment: the youtube short-url is youtu.be what would the regex look like in that case?

Comment: @xorinzor: I added a simple regex explanation.

Comment: Could you give example how is this url?

Comment: how do people write this lengthy regex?

Comment: what about this url 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mg3JgfOtf3g'

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you should look at the Youtube API and try to see if there is a way to get a videoID by parsing the URL though the API.

Look at this SO post:
[Youtube API - Extract video ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id)

Comment: its indeed what I wanted, however The Mask was first, therefor I marked his response as answer

Comment: +1 for pointing out the existing question and the API provided by the site in question.

Answer (score 5):

This could be quick:

```
var url = 'http://www.youtu.be/543221'; 
         //http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNfYz6Yw0W8&feature=g-all-esi would work also
var a = url.split("v=")[1];
a = a != undefined ? a : url.split("youtu.be/")[1];
b = a.split("&")[0];
```

the variable c will have your id. Quick. The regex is nicer... harder to read though. I have modified my code to account for both.

Comment: This is exactly what other threads have too, however I need youtu.be URL's to be validated too

Comment: Please check my code now. One more line of code is simple enough to check for what you are looking for. I think it is still more readable than the regex. However, I agree that the regex is nicer. However, since a lot of people don't speak regex, this way might make it easier to update next time youtube adds another url format. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many kind:

- latest short format: `http://youtu.be/NLqAF9hrVbY`
- iframe: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/NLqAF9hrVbY`
- iframe (secure): `https://www.youtube.com/embed/NLqAF9hrVbY`
- object param: `http://www.youtube.com/v/NLqAF9hrVbY?fs=1&hl=en_US`
- object embed: `http://www.youtube.com/v/NLqAF9hrVbY?fs=1&hl=en_US`
- watch: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLqAF9hrVbY`
- users: `http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo`
- ytscreeningroom: `http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I`
- any/thing/goes!: `http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/2/PPS-8DMrAn4`
- any/subdomain/too: `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/NLqAF9hrVbY`
- more params: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spDj54kf-vY&feature=g-vrec`
- query may have dot: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spDj54kf-vY&feature=youtu.be`
  (Source: [How do I find all YouTube video ids in a string using a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex))

The best way is limiting input-data.

Good luck

Comment: This solution works with all your urls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url/4811367#14701040

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
var url = "...";
var videoid = url.match((?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:[^\/\n\s]+\/\S+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|\S*?[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}));
if(videoid != null) {
    console.log("video id = ",videoid[1]);
} else { 
    console.log("The youtube url is not valid.");
}
```

The Regex is from
[YouTube video ID regex](https://gist.github.com/afeld/1254889)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily using preg_match here is the example:
`$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzOt12co4nk&feature=g-vrec";
preg_match('/v=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', $url, $matches);
$vid = $matches[1];`
 
 Now you will have the video id as: $vid = YzOt12co4nk;

Comment: despite the question already beeing answered, please note this was about a Javascript/JQuery solution, not PHP; thank you for the contribution though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way of doing it without using regex.

I made a function which does it for you:

```
function getLink(url){
    fetch('www.youtube.com/oembed?url=' + url).then(res => {
     var thumbnailUrl = res.thumbnail_url;
     var id = thumbnail_url.split('vi/')[1].substring(0, 11);
     return id;}
      )
}

console.log(getLink(your_url));
// here replace 'your_url' with your specified youtube url.
```

All this does is, it uses youtube api and passes your url as an parameter, and youtube take cares of the type of the url, so you dont have to worry about it. The next thing is, the function then takes the 'thumbnail_url' data from that api, and then splits the thumbnail's url accordingly to find the ID of the video.