# Seperate a youtube link to retrieve only the ID, and pass the ID into another variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube

I have looked on ways like `.split()` to seperate strings and saw a simple seperation like `.split("")`, or `.split("")` but i don't know how to do more complex like remove everything before and after the id.
What i have is a variable that contains a youtube string example:

```
var utubeLink = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/8lmuuaI09ro/0.jpg";
```

and a variable that is waiting to store the ID of the `var utubeLink`

```
var newutubeLink = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"
```

I want to remove everything so that i get `8lmuuaI09ro`, and pass the ID into `newutubeLink` so that my final result will be `http://www.youtube.com/v/8lmuuaI09ro`.

Thanks

Comment: Lots of questions related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591547/how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this, if the patterns of the URL doesn't change.

```
var utubeLink = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/8lmuuaI09ro/0.jpg";
var newutubeLink = "http://www.youtube.com/v/";
var parts = utubeLink.split('/');
var link = newutubeLink + parts[4];
console.log(link);
```