# Extracting a string from a string where the string is variable

Tags: php, youtube

I want to get the individual ID from a youtube link so that I can use it later on, to pull other information such as its thumbnail image and insert it into the embedded iframe.

I notice there that all, I hope, of the urls on youtube start `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` **Unique video ID** and then depending on a few things can end something like `&list=RD02M5u5zXVmoHM`. But the unique id always has a `&` after it and the `watch?v=` before.  Is this the best way to do it? Have a written this correctly?

```
$link=$_POST['link'];
$link_id=str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '', $link);
$link_id=strstr($link_id, '&', true);
```

This comes from form data. Is there anything other variables from youtube URLs I may encounter?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id)

Comment: So it is a little so simple what I have written. The accepted answer on that post is great. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use: http://php.net/pase_url and http://php.net/parse_str like this:

```
<?php
$info = parse_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DA57FOJSdM8");
parse_str($info["query"], $query);
print_r($query);

// Outputs: Array ( [v] => DA57FOJSdM8 )
```

Comment: so the final result is an array? What does the ['query'] part do here?

Comment: What function can I use to put the [v] of the array into a string, I can't work out which one

Comment: you can use `echo $query["v"];` or assign it to a variable `$v = $query["v"];`

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str) would be a simpler way where PHP handles the dirty work for you. Example:

```
$video_id = false;

$url_parts = parse_url($link);
$query_params = array();

if (isset($url_parts['query']))
{
    parse_str($url_parts['query'], $query_params);
}

if (isset($query_params['v']))
{
    $video_id = $query_params['v'];
}
```

And now `$video_id` contains the ID you need.