# php parse url with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP variable that contains one of two possible kind of URL:

```
$text = "http://www.youtube.com/v/wUJQPbALd68?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1";
$text = " http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcrbM1l_BoI
```

How can I extract the id from the url for the two type? I think I have to use regex but I am a very newbie.

For example in first `$text` is `wUJQPbALd68` and in the second is `IcrbM1l_BoI` .

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/**
 * get youtube video ID from URL
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string Youtube video id or FALSE if none found. 
 * @authro hakre
 */
function youtube_id_from_url($url) {
    $pattern = 
        '%^# Match any youtube URL
        (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
        (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
        (?:             # Group host alternatives
          youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
          (?:           # Group path alternatives
            /embed/     # Either /embed/
          | /v/         # or /v/
          | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
          )             # End path alternatives.
        )               # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
        $%x'
        ;
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if (false !== $result) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Youtube API - Extract video ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex)

```
// Linkify youtube URLs which are not already links.
function linkifyYouTubeURLs($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('~
        # Match non-linked youtube URL in the wild. (Rev:20130823)
        https?://         # Required scheme. Either http or https.
        (?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)? # Optional subdomain.
        (?:               # Group host alternatives.
          youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com    # or youtube.com followed by
          \S*             # Allow anything up to VIDEO_ID,
          [^\w\-\s]       # but char before ID is non-ID char.
        )                 # End host alternatives.
        ([\w\-]{11})      # $1: VIDEO_ID is exactly 11 chars.
        (?=[^\w\-]|$)     # Assert next char is non-ID or EOS.
        (?!               # Assert URL is not pre-linked.
          [?=&+%\w.-]*    # Allow URL (query) remainder.
          (?:             # Group pre-linked alternatives.
            [\'"][^<>]*>  # Either inside a start tag,
          | </a>          # or inside <a> element text contents.
          )               # End recognized pre-linked alts.
        )                 # End negative lookahead assertion.
        [?=&+%\w.-]*        # Consume any URL (query) remainder.
        ~ix', 
        '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1">YouTube link: $1</a>',
        $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "http://www.youtube.com/v/wUJQPbALd68?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1"
$text_array = explode("/", $text);
```

//then $text_array[1] equals wUJQPbALd68

```
$text = " http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcrbM1l_BoI 
$text_array = explode("=", $text);
$id = end($text_array);
```

end grabs the last array element

not tested but should work

Comment: didn't see the other answers when i posted. theres are probably better