# How to get video id from new share url pattern

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I see YouTube app updated new function to share videos with the url like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/shared?ci=8A940MXKFmQ
```

My app is using [YouTube API/videos/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get video informations and it required the Video ID field.

How can we get youtube video id from the url above.
Thanks

Comment: Check this SO question [6556559](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id) and [3392993](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id) if it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not a good way to do it, but since there seems to be no API for that, check this:

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/4080530624eda994d535e1a01c38ddd6d9aa3805

What they do is fetching the content and search for the `meta` tag with the name `videoId`. Again: Not a good way, maybe this approach stops working in a month or a year or maybe never.