# What would be the regex to get the view code from youtube urls?

Tags: javascript, regex

I just need to get the view code from youtube urls. The api is returning back strings that look like this:

```
http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=XODUrTtvZks&feature=youtube_gdata_player
```

I need to get this part:

```
XODUrTtvZks
```

from the above, keep in mind that sometimes there may be additional parameters after the v=something like:

```
&feature=youtube_gdata_player
```

and sometimes there may not be. Can someone please provide the regex that would work in this situation and an example of how to use it using javascript?

Comment: You mean like this: http://www.rubular.com/r/gETdpfrVwc.  You can look into Regular Expression for Javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: mellamokb: You answer is correct.

Comment: You may find [my answer to a very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string/5831191#5831191) question to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet only matches on URL's from youtube.com:

```
var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XODUrTtvZks&feature=youtube_gdata_player';
var matches = url.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?\s*v=([^&]+)/i);

if (matches) {
    var videoID = matches[1];
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/v=([^&]+)/` and get the match at offset 1.

Comment: And i give my own answer, dude

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online tool called RegExr to get your regular expression ,[http://gskinner.com/RegExr/].

Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is from Google’s own parser at closure:

```
function getIdFromUrl(url) {
    return /https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA_Z]{2,3}.)?(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?)((?:[\w\d\-\_\=]+&amp;(?:amp;)?)*v(?:&lt;[A-Z]+&gt;)?=([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]+))/i.exec(url)[2];
}
```

You can see it here:

http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/ui/media/youtube.js?r=1221#246