# preg_match youtube id and remove url

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to get the youtube video id and replace the url with just the youtube video id. So far I found a way to get the video id, but I can't seem to remove the url.

```
if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match)) {
    $video_id = $match[1];
}
```

Examples:

```
   http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/user/username#p/u/11/dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/0/dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ ...
```

Note that a youtube url can also have extra params after the video id.

Much help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what value are you getting? Whats not working?

Comment: by remove the URL maybe you are wanting to use preg_replace rather than just preg_match

Comment: The preg_match is working. I just can't find a way to replace the url with the video id

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regex - find all youtube video ids in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string)

Comment: @webarto my questions is not about finding the youtube id

Comment: I don't care what you want with it, regarding youtube links, all is in answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all your example urls this preg_replace works. Additionally removes any params after the video ID

```
$videoID =  preg_replace("#[&\?].+$#", "", preg_replace("#http://(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?/(embed/|watch\?v=|\?v=|v/|e/|.+/|watch.*v=|)#i", "", $url));
```

Comment: It has trouble handling params after the youtube id.

Comment: Try this string `hello my name is :) testing [tag] [/tag] http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?yup=2&t=2 hello this is another test :) ;)`

Comment: okay, edited one more time, now it should also replace the params if starting with a "?"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&foo=bar&test=baz';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $args);
echo "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=". $args['v'];
```

[codepad example](http://codepad.org/aJBStidv)