# Fix Javascript code to convert all Youtube links inside text to function with Youtube ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex - find all youtube video ids in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string)

I'm looking for a function that will allow me to change all Youtube links to Javascript function call with ID.

I will show you my code, but it's wrong... not working as i want...:

```
function find_and_replace_youtube_links(message)
{
    return message.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, 'play_youtube(\'$1\')');   
}

function play_youtube(youtube_id)
{
    $('#youtube_embed').html('something youtubeid something');   
}
```

The calling

```
    alert(find_and_replace_youtube_links('test \n\
            http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGCsyshUU&feature=autoplay&list=sSPDBAE171ADC2D71FA&playnext=1\n\
\n\
testt http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGCsyshUU&feature=autoplay&list=sSPDBAE171ADC2D71FA&playnext=1 testt\n\
\n\
testtt'));
```

And output

```
test 
            play_youtube('JGCsyshUU&feature=autoplay&list=sSPDBAE171ADC2D71FA&playnext=1')

testt play_youtube('JGCsyshUU&feature=autoplay&list=sSPDBAE171ADC2D71FA&playnext=1 testt')

testtt
```

Hmmm...

The problem is here:

```
 play_youtube('JGCsyshUU&feature=autoplay&list=sSPDBAE171ADC2D71FA&playnext=1')
```

You can see, that it parse all link, not just id
It should give me

```
play_youtube('JGCsyshUU');
```

instead of

```
play_youtube('JGCsyshUU&feature=autoplay&list=sSPDBAE171ADC2D71FA&playnext=1')
```

with is wrong

:-(

Anyone doing something similar and have working function?
I can adapt to my requirements but need to have something in common with mine requirements.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGCsyshUU-A

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is grabbing the rest of the URI's query string from the `v` parameter onwards.

What you want is to grab only the `v` parameter and ignore all following parameters.

Parameters are separated by the `&` character, so instead of matching all characters with `(.+)`, try matching all "non `&` characters" with `([^&]+)`.

Here's the modified version of the function in full:

```
function find_and_replace_youtube_links(message)
{
    return message.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^&]+).*/g, 'play_youtube(\'$1\')');   
}
```

Now this is still going to fail if you run it on text where there are any links with just the `v` parameter and no others since there will then be no `&` character either. I'll leave the full solution for that case to you as an exercise (-:

Comment: Why won't it help? It worked for me with your example text.