# Get Youtube Id from youtube embed using Regex

Tags: regex, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php regex - find all youtube video ids in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string)

How can I get the youtube Id from the embed using Regex, even it is in old format or ifarme

example

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ghc8cYOA1Vo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

or

```
<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ghc8cYOA1Vo?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ghc8cYOA1Vo?hl=en_US&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

please advice,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
youtube.com/((v|embed)/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Youtube has recently gone from 10-character IDs to 11 characters, and it's possible that they may eventually increase that number.

Comment: This doesn't account for underscores `_` which I've seen before

Answer (score 1):

Using the regexp `youtube[.]com/(v|embed)/([^"?]+)`, the YouTube ID will be captured in the second group.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?33l8b)

Comment: Yes. Because it clearly states there that you must escape forward slashes! But that's particular to Rubular. The regular expression provided definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this regex  `((v|embed))\/?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`  and it works fine

Comment: **1°)** How are you getting the YouTube ID with this regexp? **2°)** This is really a bad regexp, I'm not sure you know the common special chars... **3°)** `helloworlv-`, `va` and `v-_-` will match. I really recommand you to use mine.