# How to get YouTube channel name?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I have searched in [YouTube Documents](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) and found nothing to get others channel name from a YouTube video.

That is,

I currently would like to get the channel name from a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhNWzcUqGbI), I only have the URL, how to get the channel name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the video id from the URL, and then make an HTTP GET request:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dQw4w9WgXcQ?v=2&alt=json

where `dQw4w9WgXcQ` is the video id you're interested in.  This returns a JSON response, with the channel name in the `author` field (click the link for an example).

For more information, see [Retrieving Data for a Single Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries) and the rest of the YouTube API documentation.

See e.g. [How do I find all YouTube video ids in a string using a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex?lq=1) for some ways to get the video id from a YouTube URL.

Comment: +1 for helping me with my own similar problem. It works. I can't believe youtube API-3 doesn't have a simpler way but well... it works..

Answer (score 8):

You can do this easily by using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

The latest part in the URL after "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" is your VIDEO_ID.

Just do a [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with setting part="snippet". Then you can grab [snippet.channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.channelId) in the response.

Request would be:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=EhNWzcUqGbI&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

for your example.

You can always try these using [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list).

[Great sample codes](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

For total newbies who are lost : consider a sample function that will help understand the entire cycle of fetch, parse, display etc and bring youtube channel's videos to your tableview specifically. im not writing the tableview part here

```js
        -(void)initiateRequestToYoutubeApiAndGetChannelInfo
    {
    NSString * urlYouCanUseAsSample = @"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY_WITHOUT_CURLY_BRACES}&channelId={CHANNEL_ID_YOU_CAN_GET_FROM_ADDRESS_BAR_WITHOUT_CURLY_BRACES}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20";
    

    
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: urlYouCanUseAsSample];
    
    // Create your request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    
    
      // Send the request asynchronously remember to reload tableview on global thread
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        
        // Callback, parse the data and check for errors
        if (data && !connectionError) {
            NSError *jsonError;
            
            NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
            
            if (!jsonError) {
            // better put a breakpoint here to see what is the result and how it is brought to you. Channel id name etc info should be there

                NSLog(@"%@",jsonResult);

            /// separating "items" dictionary and making array
                                 
                // 
        id keyValuePairDict = jsonResult;
        NSMutableArray * itemList = keyValuePairDict[@"items"];
                for (int i = 0; i< itemList.count; i++) {
                    

            /// separating VIDEO ID dictionary from items dictionary and string video id
                id v_id0 = itemList[i];
                NSDictionary * vid_id = v_id0[@"id"];
                id v_id = vid_id;
                NSString * video_ID = v_id[@"videoId"];
                   
           //you can fill your local array for video ids at this point
                    
               //     [video_IDS addObject:video_ID];
                    
            /// separating snippet dictionary from itemlist array
                id snippet = itemList[i];
                NSDictionary * snip = snippet[@"snippet"];
                
            /// separating TITLE and DESCRIPTION from snippet dictionary
                id title = snip;
                NSString * title_For_Video = title[@"title"];
                NSString * desc_For_Video = title[@"description"];
                
        //you can fill your local array for titles & desc at this point 
                    
                  //  [video_titles addObject:title_For_Video];
                   // [video_description addObject:desc_For_Video];
                    
                

                    
            /// separating thumbnail dictionary from snippet dictionary

                id tnail = snip;
                NSDictionary * thumbnail_ = tnail[@"thumbnails"];
                
            /// separating highresolution url dictionary from thumbnail dictionary

                id highRes = thumbnail_;
                NSDictionary * high_res = highRes[@"high"];
                
            /// separating HIGH RES THUMBNAIL IMG URL from high res dictionary

                id url_for_tnail = high_res;
                NSString * thumbnail_url = url_for_tnail[@"url"];
       //you can fill your local array for titles & desc at this point

                    [video_thumbnail_url addObject:thumbnail_url];
                   

                }
             // reload your tableview on main thread   
        //[self.tableView    performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
         performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadInputViews) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

                
          // you can log all local arrays for convenience
             //   NSLog(@"%@",video_IDS);
              //  NSLog(@"%@",video_titles);
              //  NSLog(@"%@",video_description);
              //  NSLog(@"%@",video_thumbnail_url);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"an error occurred");
            }
        }
    }];
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
snippeturl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + video_id + "&key=" + your_api_key + "&part=snippet"
response_snippet = urlopen(snippeturl).read()
data_snippet = json.loads(response_snippet)
channel = data_snippet['items'][0]['snippet']['channelTitle']
```