# php youtube and links regex are combining and in turn rendering useless

Tags: php, regex, iframe, youtube

i have a posting feature on my site that can embed links and youtube videos. the problem is, that the two clash together, and the youtube iframe ends up being a 404 page on my site. my codes for the youtube videos and links are below, but im not sure how to stop them from combining and ruining it.
by combining, i mean this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhqiT2nWCVU turns to
`<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhqiT2nWCVU">`
which then turns into

```
<iframe src="<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhqiT2nWCVU"></a>">
```

sorry if i am unclear in any way. my codes are below.

```
function youtube($string)
{
  return preg_replace(
    '#(http://(www.)?youtube.com)?/(v/|watch\?v\=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?#i',
    '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    $string
  );
}

$posted = youtube($posted);

$rexProtocol = '(https?://)?';
$rexDomain   = '((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,63}|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})';
$rexPort     = '(:[0-9]{1,5})?';
$rexPath     = '(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';
$rexQuery    = '(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';
$rexFragment = '(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';

// Solution 1:

function callback($match)
{
    // Prepend http:// if no protocol specified
    $completeUrl = $match[1] ? $match[0] : "http://{$match[0]}";

    return '<a href="' . $completeUrl . '">'
        . $match[2] . $match[3] . $match[4] . '</a>';
}


$posted = preg_replace_callback("&\\b$rexProtocol$rexDomain$rexPort$rexPath$rexQuery$rexFragment(?=[?.!,;:\"]?(\s|$))&",
    'callback', $posted);
```

Comment: See my answer to a nearly duplicate question: [How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5831191/433790) Note that the regex in that answer skips over already-linked You-Tube URLs and will likely work quite well for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular solution to this problem is to use placeholders. On your first pass you turn all YouTube links into a placeholder, for example:

```
{{youtube:VhqiT2nWCVU}}
```

After that you run your normal link converter. And at the end your run yet another regex to turn all your palceholders into youtube embeds.

Comment: could you possibly explain this using an example?

Comment: http://rextester.com/OMOCIS38257 To see what it does press "Run it" at the bottom

Comment: Thanks @dragony I will accept your answer tommorow if it works