# improving this regex to consider youtube id with dash (-)

Tags: regex

how can i improve this regex to accommodate youtube ids that includes `-` in it?
ive tested a couple of regex i found in other threads but they didn't considered `-` within the id.

youtube links can be so complicated at times.

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iol0B-clFFM"; //valid youtube link
$pattern = "/(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^\"&\n]+|(?<=(?:v|i)=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+/";

preg_match($pattern,$url,$matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

the result from above returns only `iol0B`it stops just before the `-`

Comment: Works for me? See here https://eval.in/57480

Comment: really!? ok thats weird, ive tried this so many many times. let me recheck. thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Be warned that `_` is also a valid character for a youtube link.  Just use `[\w\d-]` if your flavor supports it.  Youtube ids are essentially base64 encoded binary digits with `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern works, but perhaps you could make it shorter:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=[vi][=/]|youtu\.be/|embed/)[a-z0-9-]+~i';
```