# Removing all Href and youtube URL and geting the ID

Tags: php, regex, youtube

```
$article = ('<p>In show business it is all about the extremes. For example the people
 below earn a whole load of money thanks to their appearance and it is not at all 
beautiful. They are some of the ugliest models but nevertheless they still work in 
full swing. They get hired in movies, commercials, and anywhere where an ugly guy 
(or a girl) is needed , and if you’re just plane average and you still wish to 
work, well then you should probably do something extreme with your body like the 
lizard man, for example.</p></a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eauCiY1MmZU">
    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eauCiY1MmZU
</a>

function tubeCodeEmbed( $vCode ) {
   return $vCode;
}

$search = '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';
$article = preg_replace($search, tubeCodeEmbed("$1"), $article);
echo $article;
```

This is what I have so far ..and it works except it does not strip hrefs from the string that have youtube in it.

### My desired output

> In show business it is all about the extremes. For example the people
>   below earn a whole load of money thanks to their appearance and it is
>   not at all beautiful. joeCiY1MmZU They are some of the ugliest models
>   but nevertheless they still work in full swing. They get hired in
>   movies, commercials, and anywhere where an ugly guy (or a girl) is
>   needed , and if you’re just plane average and you still wish to work,
>   well then you should probably do something extreme with your body like
>   the lizard man, for example. oddCiY1MmZU eauCiY1MmZU

---

Notice the ID's in the output ...no url's or href tags from youtube

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex)

Comment: I tried that ... it did not work for my needs.

Comment: @JosephPhilbert, Can you edit your question with the `output` you asking?

Comment: I need the "HREF" tags that have a youtube link/host removed also.

Comment: Try this '$html = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=href\=\")[^]]+?(?=\")/","parseID",$article);
$final = preg_replace("/<a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)<\/a>/", '', $html);
function parseID($matches){
    if (preg_match("%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^\"&?/ ]{11})%i", $matches[0], $match)) {
        $video_id = $match[1]; // Here is video id
    }
}
echo $final;'

Answer (score 0):

```
$article=explode("?v=",$article);
$article=explode("\"",$article[1]);
$youtube_id=$article[0];
```

$youtube_id will return the id of video

Answer (score 0):

See if this code will work.

Working **[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/kpc-6ev)**

```
<?php
$article = '<p>In show business it is all about the extremes. For example the people
 below earn a whole load of money thanks to their appearance and it is not at all 
beautiful. They are some of the ugliest models but nevertheless they still work in 
full swing. They get hired in movies, commercials, and anywhere where an ugly guy 
(or a girl) is needed , and if you’re just plane average and you still wish to 
work, well then you should probably do something extreme with your body like the 
lizard man, for example.</p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eauCiY1MmZU">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eauCiY1MmZU</a>';


function get_id($matches){
  parse_str( parse_url( $matches[2], PHP_URL_QUERY ), $tArr );
  return " ".$tArr["v"];
}
$string = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "",$article);
$string = str_replace("</p>", "", $string);
$string = preg_replace_callback("#<a(.+?)>(.+?)</a>#is", "get_id", $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

**Output:**

> In show business it is all about the extremes. For example the people
>   below earn a whole load of money thanks to their appearance and it is
>   not at all beautiful. They are some of the ugliest models but
>   nevertheless they still work in full swing. They get hired in movies,
>   commercials, and anywhere where an ugly guy (or a girl) is needed ,
>   and if you’re just plane average and you still wish to work, well then
>   you should probably do something extreme with your body like the
>   lizard man, for example. eauCiY1MmZU eauCiY1MmZU

Comment: Why does it have the ID twice? "eauCiY1MmZU eauCiY1MmZU" also its not supposed to remove other href links

Comment: I did it according to how you said you wanted the output. In your output update you listed the `ID twice`. See the update, I changed it. Your title also said ALL hrefs.

Comment: Ok I figured it out

This removes all href with youtube links
`$article->text = preg_replace('#<a href="https?://www.youtube.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $article->text);`

Then this gets the ID
`$ychar = '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';`

$1 is the ID (PERFECT)
`$article->text = preg_replace($ychar, $this->youtubeCodeEmbed("$1"),$article->text);`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Strip all youtube links from the $article.
    if ((preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^&]+/',$article->text))==true) {
    $article->text = preg_replace('/(<a [^>]+)>(http:\/\/*.*.youtube.*)  <\/a>|iU/iU', '$2', $article->text);
    $ychar = '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';
    $article->text = preg_replace($ychar, $this->youtubeCodeEmbed("$1"), $article->text);
    return true;
//Strip all vimeo links from the $article.
} elseif ((preg_match('/http:\/\/(.*?)vimeo\.com\/[0-9]+/', $article->text))==true) {
    $article->text = preg_replace('/(<a [^>]+)>(http:\/\/*.*.vimeo.*)<\/a>|iU/iU', '$2', $article->text);
    $vchar = '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*vimeo.com\/([0-9\-_]+)([0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i';
    $article->text = preg_replace($vchar, $this->vimeoCodeEmbed('$1'), $article->text);
    return true;
    } else {
return false;
}
```

}

After some digging and prodding this is a working solution and works so well.
First preg_replace strips all href URLs for the giving domain then ... removes the rest in the other preg_replace