# Translating a Python Conditional to JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex, translate

I'm trying to convert this python regex to a javascript regex

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/a14e1538fe66c49ca8869681d2bbe60a36bd420d/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L134-L159

```
r"""(?x)^
(
    (?:https?://|//)?                                    # http(s):// or protocol-independent URL (optional)
    (?:(?:(?:(?:\w+\.)?[yY][oO][uU][tT][uU][bB][eE](?:-nocookie)?\.com/|
    (?:www\.)?deturl\.com/www\.youtube\.com/|
    (?:www\.)?pwnyoutube\.com/|
    (?:www\.)?yourepeat\.com/|
    tube\.majestyc\.net/|
    youtube\.googleapis\.com/)                        # the various hostnames, with wildcard subdomains
    (?:.*?\#/)?                                          # handle anchor (#/) redirect urls
    (?:                                                  # the various things that can precede the ID:
        (?:(?:v|embed|e)/)                               # v/ or embed/ or e/
        |(?:                                             # or the v= param in all its forms
            (?:(?:watch|movie)(?:_popup)?(?:\.php)?/?)?  # preceding watch(_popup|.php) or nothing (like /?v=xxxx)
            (?:\?|\#!?)                                  # the params delimiter ? or # or #!
            (?:.*?&)?                                    # any other preceding param (like /?s=tuff&v=xxxx)
            v=
        )
    ))
    |youtu\.be/                                          # just youtu.be/xxxx
    |https?://(?:www\.)?cleanvideosearch\.com/media/action/yt/watch\?videoId=
    )
)?                                                       # all until now is optional -> you can pass the naked ID
([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})                                      # here is it! the YouTube video ID
(?(1).+)?                                                # if we found the ID, everything can follow
$"""
```

I removed the quotes at start and end, added start `/^` and end delimiters `/i`, escaped forward slashes, removed the free-spacing mode and ended up with this

```
var VALID_URL = /^((?:https?:\/\/|\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:(?:\w+\.)?[yY][oO][uU][tT][uU][bB][eE](?:-nocookie)?\.com\/|(?:www\.)?deturl\.com\/www\.youtube\.com\/|(?:www\.)?pwnyoutube\.com\/|(?:www\.)?yourepeat\.com\/|tube\.majestyc\.net\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/)(?:.*?\#\/)?(?:(?:(?:v|embed|e)\/)|(?:(?:(?:watch|movie)(?:_popup)?(?:\.php)?\/?)?(?:\?|\#!?)(?:.*?&)?v=)))|youtu\.be\/|https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?cleanvideosearch\.com\/media\/action\/yt\/watch\?videoId=))?([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})(?(1).+)?$/g;
```

However the javascript regex debugger I'm using says `Unexpected character "(" after "?"` in regards to the javascript transpose of this part of the python regex

```
(?(1).+)?      # if we found the ID, everything can follow
```

Any idea how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript does not support conditionals.**

But the world of regex has long survived without conditionals, and there are ways around it.

**The Idea**

The basic structure of that scary regex was this:

```
(Capture A)? (Match B) ( If A was captured, (Match C)? )
```

You can translate the **IF** into an **OR**:

```
(Capture A) (Match B) (Match C)? **OR** (Match B)
```

**Converted Regex**

Try this:

```
^((?:https?://|//)?(?:(?:(?:(?:\w+\.)?[yY][oO][uU][tT][uU][bB][eE](?:-nocookie)?\.com/|(?:www\.)?deturl\.com/www\.youtube\.com/|(?:www\.)?pwnyoutube\.com/|(?:www\.)?yourepeat\.com/|tube\.majestyc\.net/|youtube\.googleapis\.com/)(?:[^\n]*?#/)?(?:(?:(?:v|embed|e)/)|(?:(?:(?:watch|movie)(?:_popup)?(?:\.php)?/?)?(?:\?|#!?)(?:[^\n]*?&)?v=)))|youtu\.be/|https?://(?:www\.)?cleanvideosearch\.com/media/action/yt/watch\?videoId=)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})(?:[^\n]+)?)|^([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})
```

**Explanation**

The `(?(1)[^\n]+)?` conditional tries to optionally match `[^\n]+` if Group 1 is set. Since it occurs after the non-optional `([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})`, I transformed the conditional into an alternation `|`

- I make no judgment about the suitability of the regex... I rearranged the "grammar" without looking at the "words". :)
- Either we match that whole Group 1, into which we now directly roll the `([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})` and the optional component, **OR**
- We directly match the `([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})`
- If you are interested in retrieving the `([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})`, depending on which side of the alternation matches it, it will live inside a different capture Group. I'll leave you to count the parentheses.
- There are probably lots of parentheses you can remove, depending on your needs

**Reference**

- [Conditional Regex 101](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html)
- [If-Then-Else Conditionals in Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Comment: Terrific, glad it worked. FYI, I posted some references about conditionals. See you next time! :)

Comment: Thanks again, this is a good website I've been using to visualize how a regex works https://www.debuggex.com/.

Comment: I was a little confused about something.  I created a jsfiddle and noticed one use case of a url is passing when it should not.  http://jsfiddle.net/hd6E3/2/ We expect ids with only `[0-9A-Za-z_-]` to work but this url passes `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNu+bNAiaSA&feature=youtube_gdata_player` even though it has a `+` symbol in the video id

Comment: FYI, added an explanation about the logic of the translation. Will take a look at your fiddle... But I was interested in the translation, not analyzing the regex. :)

Comment: By the way have you seen this highly upvoted post in the FAQ about [matching YouTube IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex)?

Comment: Just so you know, I'm looking at it. Not sure what's going on yet. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55892/discussion-between-zx81-and-user784637).

Comment: GOT IT!!! I hadn't noticed the `^` at the very top, before the huge parenthesis. It applies to the whole regex, so it needs to be distributed on each side of the OR. You know, as in 2*(3+4) = 2*3 + 2*4. Without it, the right side of the OR matched in an unanchored position. Added it in the right place on the answer. :)