# Parse youtube video ID from multiple different link style/formats?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to use Regular Expression to scan through the following scenarios and return the youtube video ID of the specific video.

```
youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&index=2&list=PLsBI83Bzbnacim19bTUONClIGpT22Zfkw
```

All of the following cases should capture just `dQw4w9WgXcQ` (the raw video ID)

Any idea of what regex I'd use to capture this? Keep in mind that youtube links can also include `-`'s and `_`'s, so `\w+` will not always capture the video ID properly.

Thanks!

Comment: So `/https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig` would give me what I want...? Is there any way to... shorten this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. I believe this is a duplicate of ["How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex), however it provided a very lengthy regex to accept many cases that I wouldn't encounter.

The following regex worked and captured only what I wanted: `/(?:\.be\/|watch\?v=)([^\s&]+)/`

Sorry and thanks!