# Grab URL within a string which contains HTML code

Tags: php

I have a string, for example:

```
$html = '<p>hello<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HknMcG2qYo">world</a></p><p>hello<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=37373o">world</a></p>';
```

And I want to search the string for the **first** URL that starts with `youtube.com` or `youtu.be` and store it in variable `$first_found_youtube_url`.

How can I do this efficiently?

I can do a `preg_match` or `strpos` looking for the urls but not sure which approach is more appropriate.

Comment: The appropriate thing to do, would probably be to use a parser and parse it as what it is, HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo Can you please elaborate? I don't understand your approach. English is not my first language and I don't pickup on technical terms that easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this function a while back, it uses regex and returns an array of unique urls. Since you want the first one, you can just use the first item in the array.

```
function getUrlsFromString($string) {
    $regex = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    $matches = array_unique($matches[0]);           
    usort($matches, function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    });
    return $matches;
}
```

Example:

```
$html = '<p>hello<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HknMcG2qYo">world</a></p><p>hello<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=37373o">world</a></p>';
$urls = getUrlsFromString($html);
$first_found_youtube = $urls[0];
```

With YouTube specific regex:

```
function getYoutubeUrlsFromString($string) {
    $regex = '#(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com\/watch\?v=|youtu.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]*))#i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    $matches = array_unique($matches[0]);           
    usort($matches, function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
    });
    return $matches;
}
```

Example:

```
$html = '<p>hello<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HknMcG2qYo">world</a></p><p>hello<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=37373o">world</a></p>';
$urls = getYoutubeUrlsFromString($html);
$first_found_youtube = $urls[0];
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure if this is the best approach but I'll bite. Can you please alter the regex to only include youtube.com and youtu.be links?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson try this `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com\/watch\?v=|youtu.be\/)(.*)` - the only capture group contains the video ID

Comment: @TylerSebastian Thanks for the post but seems quite incomplete. E.g. http should be there and https...

Comment: @HenrikPetterson it is there... do you mean captured? just put brackets around the whole thing: `(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com\/watch\?v=|youtu.be\/)(.*))` - the first capture group would be the whole thing, the second would be the video id.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Please try the following to understand the problem: http://pastebin.com/6zS2fAus

Comment: Use `(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com\/watch\?v=|youtu.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]*))`. http://regexr.com/3cfhn

Comment: Thanks @TylerSebastian - updated answer to include your regex with a rewritten function.

Comment: Make sure you make your regex in-case-sensitive (`#i`) in case you get capital links like `HTTP://WWW.WEBSITE.NET`.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @skrilled I have a request. I will bounty this question with 100 points when eligible given that I'm asking for something beyond the initial question. Can you please make the regex identify all types of YouTube links, there are more than I thought, here is the list with a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5831191/1185126 And then, can you make the this function convert it into a simply youtube.com/watch?v=... type of URL? The answer I linked already has all of this, just can't figure out how to merge these together into one function.

Answer (score 1):

you can parse the html with DOMDocument and look for youtube url's with stripos, something like this

```
$html = '<p>hello<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HknMcG2qYo">world</a></p><p>hello<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=37373o">world</a></p>';
$DOMD = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

foreach($DOMD->getElementsByTagName("a") as $url)
{
    if (0 === stripos($url->getAttribute("href") , "https://www.youtube.com/") || 0 === stripos($url->getAttribute("href") , "https://www.youtu.be"))
    {
        $first_found_youtube_url = $url->getAttribute("href");
        break;
    }
}
```

personally, i would probably use

```
"youtube.com"===parse_url($url->getAttribute("href"),PHP_URL_HOST)
```

though, as it would get http AND https links.. which is probably what you want, though strictly speaking, not what you're asking for in top post right now..

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are looking for, I have used `preg_match_all` simply because I find it easier to debug the regexes.

```
<?php

$html = '<p>hello<a href="https://www.youtu.be/watch?v=7HknMcG2qYo">world</a></p><p>hello<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=37373o">world</a></p>';

$pattern = '/https?:\/\/(www\.)?youtu(\.be|\com)\/[a-zA-Z0-9\?=]*/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);

// print_r($matches);
$first_found_youtube = $matches[0][0];
echo $first_found_youtube;
```

- **demo** - https://3v4l.org/lFjmK